# Crosswalk between FIPS codes and Wikipedia articles about U.S. Census Places

Tags: data-request, us-census, wikipedia

The English Wikipedia includes an article for nearly every U.S. Census Place. Has anyone published a crosswalk from FIPS codes of these places to Wikipedia urls?

Is this something that would be possible with wikidata?

Comment: `SELECT * WHERE { ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> ; schema:about/wdt:P774 ?fips }`? For FIPS 6-4, replace `wdt:P774` with `wdt:P882`.

Comment: best question/info i've seen in quite awhile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this something that would be possible with Wikidata?

Yes, this is possible:

- There are the [FIPS 55-3](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P774) and [FIPS 6-4](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P882) properties in Wikidata;
- Wikidata contains information about the so-called sitelinks (see [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6050/16193)).

[Try](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Ffips_code%20%3Fwikipedia_article%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fwikidata_item%20wdt%3AP774%20%3Ffips_code%20.%0A%20%20%3Fwikipedia_article%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fwikidata_item%20.%0A%20%20%3Fwikipedia_article%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Ffips_code) the  following query:

```
 SELECT ?fips_code ?wikipedia_article WHERE {
  ?wikidata_item wdt:P774 ?fips_code .
  ?wikipedia_article schema:about ?wikidata_item .
  ?wikipedia_article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> .
} ORDER BY ?fips_code
```

If you need FIPS 6-4 codes instead of FIPS 55-3 ones, replace `wdt:P774` with `wdt:P882`.